# Access to database in a listener Circular reference

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

I am trying to access a DB using the EntityManager in my event listener but I got the following error and I do not know where the problem is.

> ServiceCircularReferenceException in PhpDumper.php line 508:
>   Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.default_connection", path: "doctrine.dbal.default_connection".

### services.yml

```
testListener:
    class:    'AppBundle\Event\MyListener'
    arguments: ['@mailer','@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

### MyListener

```
use AppBundle\Service\Mailer;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MyListener
{
  private $mailer;
  protected $em;
function __construct(Mailer $mailer ,EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args){//.....}
}
```

Comment: It is a by product of the way Symfony defines doctrine services.  The entity manager is actually dependent on all the doctrine listeners which precludes have a listener be dependent on the entity manager.  Just pull the entity manager from $args and all will be well: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events